# Redis delete item in sorted set

Tags: redis

I am using Redis to implement a 'feed' system in my social networking app similar to Instagram/facebook.

I have a key `"user:id:feed"` which contains a sorted set of ids that point to pictures. What I am wondering is, when a particular photo is deleted, how can I make sure that photo id is also deleted in all feeds that contain that photo id?

Would I have to loop through each and every feed set and delete it? Is that a common pattern in redis?

Thanks

Comment: My two cents : Using MongoDB to implement such feed structure is better suited and as it handles id based data operations in nested structures as well. You can keep all relevant information of user in one row and then retrieve and delete it in one call.

Answer (score 2):

The common pattern in Redis is to cross-reference items in various data structures. You have to do it explicitly (there is no automatic referential integrity mechanism with Redis).

Here you have a many-to-many relationship between feeds and photos. If you need to add/remove both feeds and photos, you will probably want to use 2 distinct data structures to materialize this relationship.

```
user:id:feed  ->  sorted sets of photo:n (referring to photos)
photo:n       ->  set of user:id:feed (referring to feeds)
```

So you can efficiently retrieve the photos from the feeds, and the feeds from the photos. For instance to delete a photo:

- retrieve the feeds from photo:n
- pipeline several ZREM operations (one per user:id::feed)

So the delete operation is finally costing two roundtrips. You can decrease to 1 roundtrip by using a Lua server-side script.